# Problema con el mysql conector

Tags: netbeans

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, por mi consulta les cuento que estoy relazando mi primer programa en netbeans 12.0, ya que anteriormente lo hacia en netbeans 8.2, ahora investigando y cambiando los códigos siempre me envía este error en la librería de mysql-connector-java-8.0.29, me abre bien la base de datos, pero cuando voy al menú principal una vez que haya ingresado el nombre de usuario y su clave respectiva me arroja esta advertencia o error:

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:\C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\mysql-connector-java-8.0.29\mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!\menus\Mdimenu.class
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
at net.rwx.netbeans.netesta.files.CompiledFileObserver.restoreDirectoryTreeWatcherForPath(CompiledFileObserver.java:123)
at net.rwx.netbeans.netesta.files.CompiledFileObserver.loadWatchServices(CompiledFileObserver.java:80)
at net.rwx.netbeans.netesta.files.CompiledFileObserver.start(CompiledFileObserver.java:71)
at net.rwx.netbeans.netesta.NetestaHandler.init(NetestaHandler.java:42)
at net.rwx.netbeans.netesta.DataObjectOpenAndCloseListener.addChangeListenerIfTestableSourceCode(DataObjectOpenAndCloseListener.java:76)
at net.rwx.netbeans.netesta.DataObjectOpenAndCloseListener.addChangeListenerIfTestableSourceCode(DataObjectOpenAndCloseListener.java:69)
at net.rwx.netbeans.netesta.DataObjectOpenAndCloseListener.propertyChange(DataObjectOpenAndCloseListener.java:52)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.RegistryImpl.doFirePropertyChange(RegistryImpl.java:304)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.RegistryImpl.topComponentOpened(RegistryImpl.java:163)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.notifyRegistryTopComponentOpened(WindowManagerImpl.java:1223)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.notifyTopComponentOpened(WindowManagerImpl.java:1191)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.Central.addModeOpenedTopComponent(Central.java:773)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.ModeImpl.addOpenedTopComponent(ModeImpl.java:333)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.topComponentOpenAtTabPosition(WindowManagerImpl.java:1309)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.topComponentOpen(WindowManagerImpl.java:1266)
at org.openide.windows.TopComponent.open(TopComponent.java:472)
at org.openide.windows.TopComponent.open(TopComponent.java:452)
at org.openide.windows.CloneableOpenSupport.openCloneableTopComponent(CloneableOpenSupport.java:183)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.openFormEditor(FormEditorSupport.java:217)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDataNode$1.actionPerformed(FormDataNode.java:66)
at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$PopupSupport.mouseClicked(TreeView.java:1584)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:269)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:269)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:269)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6542)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

he buscado a través de internet alguna ayuda en estos pero no he encontrado nada, favor de asesorarme, a lo mejor pienso que me falta alguna librería o en los import que estoy obviando, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: [acá](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html) te dejo la documentación oficial de Netbeans sobre como conectarte con MySql

Comment: @Liyo muchas gracias lo solucione en parte, pero me da advertencia y no el error de antes, ahora me da ala advertencia en la class de frmingreso.